# Get absolute path of file why traversing through another directory

Tags: python

I have a small snipped in python which intends to traverse through all the directory , subdirectory and manitain a list of absolute path of all the files .

code:

```
import os , pickle
root="/home/me/programs/"
l = [] #Will have list of all the files parsed through
for dname,subdirlist,flist in os.walk(root):
 for fname in flist:
  l.append(os.path.abspath(fname))
```

Even though i am parsing through all the files , my output is prefixing `/home/me/programs/` irrespective of the actual absolute path.

For example, instead of having 
`'/home/me/programs/cpp/sample/test.c'` 
i will have `'/home/me/programs/test.c'`

How do i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [`os.walk` doc](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk), you'll have to join the root path to your fname to get the absolute path :

```
import os , pickle
root="/home/me/programs/"
l = [] #Will have list of all the files parsed through
for dname,subdirlist,flist in os.walk(root):
    for fname in flist:
        l.append(os.path.join(dname, fname))
```